# input radio check only one time

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my project I've a `ngFor` for the element and the `radio input`. The problem is, I can't be sure that when I select one, the other will deselect itself.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let interventoStrutturale of interventi">
         <td style="float: left;">{{interventoStrutturale.intervento.codice}} {{interventoStrutturale.variante}} - {{interventoStrutturale.intervento.descrizione}}</td>
         <td style="float: right;">
              <label class="form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [value]="interventoStrutturale.prezzoRiepilogo" (change)="onChangeIntervento($event.target.value)">
              </label>
         </td>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Based on the input that I then select through a select I should have other values.

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChangeEnergetico($event.target.value)">
     <option value selected="0">Seleziona</option>
     <option [value]="interventoEn.prezzoRiepilogo" *ngFor="let interventoEn of interv">{{interventoEn.intervento.codice}} - {{interventoEn.intervento.descrizione}}</option>
</select>
```

The value I have to get from the first input must remain the same, but I have to make sure that it is selected only once by changing. How can I do?

Comment: A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same `name`. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group

Comment: @DanieleVallorani please take a look at my solution when you have a chance and let me know if there’s anything I can do to improve it

Answer (score 2):

All your radio buttons simply need to share the same name and they will reliably un-check as needed per their native spec ([W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20161214/examples/radio/radio-1/radio-1.html)).

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="1">Test option #1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="2">Test option #2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="3">Test option #3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="4">Test option #4</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="5">Test option #5</label>
```